# Problems executing shellcode via nop-sled

Tags: buffer-overflow

My shellcode instructions are changing during execution. I'm not sure why.

Here is what my shellcode looks like:

```
=> 0xbffff0b3:  nop
   0xbffff0b4:  nop
   0xbffff0b5:  xor    eax,eax
   0xbffff0b7:  push   eax
   0xbffff0b8:  push   0x68732f2f
   0xbffff0bd:  push   0x6e69622f
   0xbffff0c2:  mov    ebx,esp
   0xbffff0c4:  push   eax
   0xbffff0c5:  push   esp
   0xbffff0c6:  push   ebx
   0xbffff0c7:  mov    al,0x3b
   0xbffff0c9:  push   eax
   0xbffff0ca:  int    0x80
```

I step through my code and everything looks fine at first:

```
   0xbffff0b5: xor    eax,eax
   0xbffff0b7: push   eax
   0xbffff0b8: push   0x68732f2f
=> 0xbffff0bd: push   0x6e69622f
   0xbffff0c2: mov    ebx,esp
   0xbffff0c4: push   eax
   0xbffff0c5: push   esp
   0xbffff0c6: push   ebx
```

Suddenly, when I get to *mov ebx, esp*  , the remaining instructions change:

```
   0xbffff0b7: push   eax
   0xbffff0b8: push   0x68732f2f
   0xbffff0bd: push   0x6e69622f
=> 0xbffff0c2: mov    ebx,esp
   0xbffff0c4: das    
   0xbffff0c5: bound  ebp,QWORD PTR [ecx+0x6e]
   0xbffff0c8: das    
   0xbffff0c9: das
```

Here is how I compiled the program:

`gcc vuln.c -o vuln -fno-stack-protector -z execstack`

Any explanations on what is going on here would be great!

Comment: @Begueradj How is this off-topic? It's about fixing broken shellcode, which is certainly on-topic here. It's not strictly a single-person fix, because others may also presume that they can use `push` in stack-based shellcode without it breaking.

Comment: @Polynomial Coding and debugging are inherent to StackOverflow

Comment: @Begueradj This is specific enough to security that it is on-topic here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your shellcode is on the stack. I presume that your `esp` register is set to `0xbffff0c4`. You pushed `0x6e69622f` (2F 62 69 6E), which corresponds to

```
2F        das
62 69 6E  bound  ebp,QWORD PTR [ecx+0x6e]
```

This pushes your broken instructions inside your shellcode. It breaks because of this. You can't push when you've got shellcode on your stack!

Comment: Nice concise explanation

Comment: On this topic, you can use [Defuse x86 online assembler](https://defuse.ca/online-x86-assembler.htm) to assemble instructions into bytes online, or do the reverse with [ODA Online Disassembler](https://www.onlinedisassembler.com/odaweb/). Both really useful tools for quickly checking how instructions/bytes assemble or disassemble.

Comment: I generally use [radare2](http://www.radare.org/r/) for my assembly needs :)

Comment: @raz That's useful too, but an online solution gives you access to both assembly and disassembly on any platform, including phones, from pretty much anywhere. Also, ODA supports almost every modern-ish processor and instruction set ever invented, which is kinda awesome.

Comment: Any recommendations on how to fix this?
Should I change the stack pointer to point somewhere else as part of my shellcode?
Or make the shellcode as an environment variable?

Comment: @bjax15 I don't know what you're trying to exploit, or why you need to push those values to the stack. You could indeed set `esp` to an address you know to contain allocated read+write protected pages if you really do need use of a stack. Or of course you could execute an `add esp, +0x????` to move the stack pointer relative to the current value, for reliability.